# how to run children UI in python PyQt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I have main ui, and want to run children ui on click in main ui.
children:

```
class sessionGenerator(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, designTg.Ui_MainWindow2):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.showHelp.clicked.connect(self.showHelpFull)

        self.next_1.clicked.connect(self.nextOne)

        self.next_2.clicked.connect(self.nextTwo)

        self.next_3.clicked.connect(self.nextThree)

    # all another code
```

if I use

```
app2 = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window2 = sessionGenerator()

window2.show()

app2.exec_()
```

it appears on a second and throws `0xC0000005`

just sessionGenerator runs great itself. But i can't figure out how to run it from another ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create second main application. 
only

```
window2 = sessionGenerator()
window2.show()
```

This lines need to be  before first app exec.

```
app.exec_()
```